# Proving input-to-state stability for a set of equilibria

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes

Consider the following nonlinear system:
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -axy \\
\dot{y} &= axy - by
\end{align}
It's easy to check that this system has a continuum of equilibria (of the form $(x,0)$). I'm trying to prove the perturbed version of this system
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -axy +u_1(t)\\
\dot{y} &= axy - by+u_2(t)
\end{align}
is input-to-state stable, i.e, there exist $\beta \in KL$ and $\gamma \in K$ such that

$$
|x(t)|\leq \beta (|x_{0}|,t)+\gamma (\|u\|_{\infty }).
$$

I'm not sure how to do that since the system doesn't have an isolated equilibria and most of the results for input-to-state stability seem to be concerned for that particular case. Moreover, I'm not sure how to find a Lyapunov function for the system.

Comment: ISS implies global asymptotic stability. globally asymptotic systems do not have a continuum of equilibria so your system is not ISS. To see why, consider $u = 0$ and see the condition implies asymptotic stability. You could instead consider the dynamics transverse to the set of equilibria.

Comment: For the dynamics with $u=0$, I have shown that the set of the form $(x,0)$ is globally asymptotically stable, because all the solutions converge to a point in the set (which might be different depending on the initial conditions). What I am trying to prove is that this set is ISS. I know the ISS definition is usually applied to a single equilibrium point, but here I am trying to show that a similar condition shows for this continuum of equilibria.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at the literature on ecological and epidemiological systems as many of those systems have this structure. In fact, this model is the model of a reaction network with mass-action kinetics. So, you may also look at the literature on that topic.

Also, if you are actually working on that, you may need to explicitly consider the positivity of the variables. For instance, you may take the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x+y$. In this case, you have $\dot{V}(x,y)=-by$ and you can prove the asymptotic stability of the continuum of equilibrium points. Perhaps, you can use a variation of this Lyapunov function for your purpose.